# Bluetooth not working with Ralink RT3290 In Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, 22.04, bluetooth, ralink

I am using HP notebook 650 laptop and the bluetooth is not working

```
rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
sudo btmgmt info
Index list with 0 items
```

```
inxi --bluetooth
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Ralink RT3290 Bluetooth driver: rtbt
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 1 state: down
    bt-service: enabled,running rfk-block: hardware: no software: no
    address: F4:B7:E2:5A:C1:34
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this module, it should works. Or, at least, in my case did: [module](https://github.com/loimu/rtbth-dkms)